# Callback function of requestExportSession is never called. Issue only happens on iOS 13

Tags: swift, swift4, ios13, phimagemanager

I have a problem when trying to get a video file from the user's device.

This is the function that worked on iOS 12 which seems correct to me. The requestExportSession function is being called but never executes the callback code. I'm using Swift 4.

```
private func getVideo(asset:AssetViewModel, completion: @escaping (contentData?) -> ()) {

    guard let avAsset = asset.video else {completion(nil); return}
    guard self.createTempDirectory() == true else {completion(nil); return}

    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    let fileName = (avAsset as! AVURLAsset).url.lastPathComponent
    let exportFileName = "\(asset.uuid).\(self.vidExt)"
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("upload").appendingPathComponent(exportFileName)
    var fileSize: Int = 0
    var success:Bool = false

    let videoGroup = DispatchGroup()

    videoGroup.enter()

    PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(forVideo: asset.image, options: options, exportPreset: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720) { (exportSession, info) in
        guard let exportSession = exportSession else {success = false; videoGroup.leave(); return}
        exportSession.outputURL = fileURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            if exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                let asset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL)
                fileSize = asset.fileSize ?? 0
                success = true
                videoGroup.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    videoGroup.wait()

    if success {
        completion(contentData(imageURL: fileURL, fileSize: fileSize, uuid: asset.uuid, fileName: fileName, ext: self.vidExt))
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with the AVAssetExportPreset1280x720.